# Postgres: One loop to extract data from Multiple Functions

Tags: postgresql

I have about 10 functions I have already created in PostgreSQL that all output 3 column tables. I can't figure out how to create a loop that would extract all the data from the these functions and create one giant table. If someone could just guide me in the right direction of how to start that would be great.

Comment: `UNION ALL`? Or do you mean loop in one of the scripting languages?

Comment: I know in PostgreSQL you can create loops such as

LOOP
BEGIN    
        Execute format(
        'INSERT INTO Table
            SELECT %s AS "column",*
            FROM table"(%s)'
    column, column);

I want a loop that can go through my database and take out two columns from each function to create one big table

Comment: @GoGo14 I'm with Jakub. If you just need to put all the rows together, possibly change the result set, and your current functions are `RETURNS TABLE`, then a `SELECT [your columns] FROM [function call] UNION ALL [same SELECT for other functions]` should be all you need. You can create a `FUNCTION` of `LANGUAGE SQL` if you *really* need it, but you probably don't. Manual loops are something to be avoided when using PostgreSQL; they are almost always less efficient than what PG would come up with.